# STFail in block

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-blocks, ocunit, sentestingkit

When running tests using SenTestingKit, they don't fail correctly inside a block, e.g.

```
operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                            success:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id jsonObject){
                                                                STFail(@"This does not fail");
                                                            }
                                                            failure:^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id jsonObject){
                                                                STFail(@"Neither does this");
                                                            }];
[operation start];
STFail(@"But this fails fine");
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that you have an asynchronous call. Which means that the it returns immediately and your last STFail is hit.

There are solutions to be had. [How to unit test asynchronous APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162213/how-to-unit-test-asynchronous-apis)